# Find the radius of convergence of $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} 2^kx^{2k}$ using the root or ratio test

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, power-series

How do we find the radius of convergence of $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} 2^kx^{2k}$ using the root or ratio test? I know there is a solution by rewriting the terms like $(2k^2)^k$ and using what we know about convergence of geometric series. However I want to try using the root test but I am not sure how to rewrite the series in order to apply it. I need to rewrite the series in the form : $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} a_{k}x^{k}$

Comment: Maybe substitute $t=x^2$ and investigate the nicer power series $\sum_{k=0}^\infty 2^k t^k$?

Comment: For either test it will be $(2x^2)^k$.

Answer (score 0):

You need to rewrite the series in the form: $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} a_k$ :

Take $a_k=2^kx^{2k}$ and apply the ratio test.

We have $|\dfrac{a_{k+1}}{a_k}|=2|x|^2$ for all $k \geq 0 \implies \lim_{k \to \infty} |\dfrac{a_{k+1}}{a_k}| = 2|x|^2.$

Using ratio test, we have

$\begin{align} 2|x|^2 < 1 & \implies |x| < \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \\ &\implies  \text{The radius of convergence is } \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}.\end{align}$